# AppInventor's TinyDB possibilities and limits

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am a total beginner with programming and I have a little experience with mostly python, php and html.

I need to realize a very simple app for my smartphone that allows me to track a simple YES or NO every month for every customer.

It's strange but I need it to be like this.

So, asking for (e.g.) the March report the app would show me all user names and a simple YES or NO describing if that username paid me or not.

I can do this easily with an xls file but I want to realize it for fun and learning.

My question is: can I achieve a similar result (I need an Insert page where I insert customers, a modify page and a report page) simply using AppInventor?
Is TinyDB enough for this?

I could skip all this and realize a very simple webapp in php with mysql but I really dream about doing something "mine" and see it run on android.

I'd like to be able to realize it in a very simple and fast way: if AppInventor is not enough is there another solution "for dummies"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: can I achieve a similar result (I need an Insert page
>   where I insert customers, a modify page and a report page) simply
>   using AppInventor? Is TinyDB enough for this?

yes, that's easily possible, to start with App Inventor, do the [tutorials](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/tutorials.html) to get to know how everything works
also helpful in your case is to learn, how lists work in App Inventor, [more info see here](http://www.appinventorblocks.com/appinventor-tutorials-tips/appinventor-lists)
there is also a very helpful [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/programming-with-app-inventor) in case you get stuck

Comment: Can you please provide me a bit of the concept I should be working and studying around? I can store data but I don't know how to recall it. The tag concept sounds so limiting... How can I realize something like in my question with TinyDB? Even a very simple example of the logic I should use could be of a great help.

Comment: see my answer in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/programming-with-app-inventor/7Ds-Ze1sfAE/Kxwb8jYrXGsJ)...